# R how to check each element then return a boolean

Tags: r, matrix

I want to check a list named "answer,if it contains FALSE element,then return a boolean (F),if there is no any FALSE element,in other words all TRUE,return a boolean (T)
here is the code(not good too many lines,but I don't know the easier one)

```
    >answer=c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)
    >l=length(answer)
    >ind <- 1
    >t=0
    >f=0
    >while(ind<(length(answer)+1)){
    >ifelse(answer[ind]==TRUE,t<-t+1,f<-f+1)
    >ind<-ind+1
    >}
    >ifelse(f>0,print("False"),print("True"))
```

This part code could give me right result.BUT it give me twice!!
like this:

```
[1] "True"
[1] "True"
```

WHY WHY give me twice...please help me I don't want to use this function so many lines

Comment: have you tried `all(answer)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get the print twice is that `ifelse(f>0,print("False"),print("True"))` will first evaluate `f>0` (which is TRUE), and then evaluate `print("False")` (which will result in "False" being printed to the console), and finally the ifelse will  return the value of `print("False")` ("False") which will then be auto-printed to the console (the second print).

To get around the double print you could replace your last line with

```
> ifelse(f>0,"False","True")
```

Note however that neither this code or your code is returning booleans, both of them are returning character-strings. If you want a boolean you should instead use

```
> ifelse(f>0,FALSE,TRUE)
```

There are however a number of things that could be done to improve this code. You could use a for-loop to iterate directly over the `answer` vector (eliminating the need for the `ind` variable. Even better, you could use the fact that R is allowing you to add the value of two booleans (TRUE=1, and FALSE=0), so `sum(answer)` will give you the number of TRUE-values in the vector.

The easiest way to solve this is doing what baptiste is hinting at `all(answer)` will evaluate to TRUE if answer only contains TRUE-values, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Thank you your time...yes the old one works and the all(answer) also works. thank you